# How to quickly count files/folders in a directory by age?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to get a count of all files or folders older than 1 day in /tmp with:

```
find /tmp/* -ctime +1 | wc -l
```

This takes 30 minutes to run. However, `ls /tmp | wc -l` runs in a second and shows there's only about 50,000 files.

Why is `find` so slow? How do I speed it up?

Edit: You can simulate this situation yourself by running:

```
 python -c "import tempfile, os; [os.close(tempfile.mkstemp()[0]) for i in range(50000)]"
```

and then running my `find` command.

Comment: @anubhava `-not` is a GNU extension, GNU find also has `-printf` which is faster than `-exec printf`. What makes find slow here is the `-ctime +1` primary, find calls `stat` system call to evaluate it for each and every file/directory, so printing and counting chars wouldn't make a noticeable performance improvement

Comment: Oh okay, but other points I made still counts

Comment: @anubhava Why would I want to exclude symbolic links? I want to count them too.

Comment: Counting `50000` files using your `find` command took `0.53` seconds on my system. I suspect some bad symlinks or NFS paths present in your `/tmp/` directory.

Comment: Worth noting that 'ls /tmp' will simply extract the list of files in /tmp. No need to stat the file - just few readdir/getdents call. Whereas find /tmp/* -ctime will force a stat on every file + recursive visiting into sub folder. Most likely, ls -l will take longer to execute, as per-file stat will be used forced.

Comment: Yeah, that only takes 287ms on my box with over 50k files. Something else is causing your find to take a half hour.  What happens when you run `ls -l` instead of just `ls`?

Answer (score 0):

## List today files via ls and count files/folders inside tmp folder:

#### Example:

```
ls -R -al --time-style=+%D /tmp | grep `date +%D`|wc -l
```

#### This will list today files only as you asking for, change date after your needs.